# creating an array from a TIF

Tags: python, arrays, tiff, gdal

I am trying to create an array from a single band TIF image using GDAL:
example

```
array= band4.ReadAsArray(0,0,xsize,ysize)
```

but it comes out as only zeros?

```
array
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

Is there a way around this or another way to create the array? The image is unsigned 16 bit...

Comment: And you are sure it is all zeros right, or are you guessing that from the above print? You can try printing np.max(array) to see if you have anything > 0.

Comment: And just a note: If you want to read the entire image as array, you can use ReadAsArray without any parameters. I find that somewhat simpler (I am guessing that xsize and ysize is meant as the image size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @the_cheff stated in the comments, it is not necessary to pass any parameter when calling `band.ReadAsArray()`. Calling just the function will return a numpy array of the whole band.

The function structure is as follows:

`band.ReadAsArray([xoff], [yoff], [win_xsize], [win_ysize], [buf_xsize], [buf_ysize], [buf_obj])`

where,

- `xoff` is the column to start reading at. Default is 0 (first column).
- `yoff` is the row to start reading at. Default is 0 (first row).
- `win_xsize` is the number of columns to read. Default is to read them all.
- `win_ysize` is the number of rows to read. Default is to read them all.
- `buf_xsize` is the number of columns in the output array. Default is to use the `win_xsize` value. Data will be resampled if this value is different than `win_xsize`.
- `buf_ysize` is the number of rows in the output array. Default is to use the `win_ysize` value. Data will be resampled if this value is different than `win_ysize`.
- `buf_obj` is a NumPy array to put the data into instead of creating a new array. Data will be resampled, if needed, to fit into this array. Values will also be converted to the data type of this array.

I would confirm that the band has indeed values different than 0 and that it is the band you're trying to read. In some cases the band #4 is used as an alpha channel with values that range from 0 to 1.